# Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?) using Jest

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, nrwl-nx, nrwl, jest-preset-angular

I am trying to run my tests and I get this error while testing nx(mono-repo) angular test using Jest

```
Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).

      at syntaxError (../packages/compiler/src/util.ts:100:17)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata ......
```

**login-form.componenet.spec.ts**

```js
import { LoginFormComponent } from './login-form.component';
import { ComponentFixture, async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

describe('Testing LoginForm', () => {
  let component: LoginFormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginFormComponent>;

  // create new instance of FormBuilder
  const formBuilder: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginFormComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
      providers: [{ provide: FormBuilder, useValue: formBuilder }]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  test('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**test.setup.ts**

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular';
```

**jest.config.ts**

```js
module.exports = {
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  resolver: '@nrwl/jest/plugins/resolver',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html'],
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@neural/(.*)': '<rootDir>/libs/$1/src/index.ts',    
  }
};
```

**Versions**

```js
Angular: 8.2.14
jest: 26.0.1
nrwl: 8.8.2
jest-preset-angular: 7.1.1
```

constructor parameters of Login-form
**Login-form.component.ts**

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
  }
```

Let me know if you need more information to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: Required for more information: Version of `Angular` / `nrwl` / `jest` / `jest-preset-angular`, content of referenced `index.ts` (refercenced by `import from '..'`), constructor parameters of `LoginFormComponent`.
Also: why do you import `reflect` polyfill? Why do you use `reset`- / `initTestEnvironment`?

Comment: Edited, Thank you.

Comment: Can you also share the content of your `index.ts`? Maybe try referencing the `LoginFormComponent`-file directly when importing `LoginFormComponent`.

Comment: Updated, I tried importing directly and then referenced it, still same error, Thanks.

Comment: I cannot find anything unusual in the files provided. I even setup a project with your versions and your login component and the tests run flawlessly.
I guess you have to dig deeper on your own. Maybe try to start with a fresh project as well and compare the differences.

Comment: Is it  a Plain Angular Project? cause this works fine in aan Angular Project but, does not work in an NX.

Comment: Yeah, see here: https://github.com/wtho/jest-62527713-repro

Comment: I had Jest Cli installed globally and I was trying with Jest command, I removed jest cli and used angular cli command it then worked for me.

Comment: please formulate an answer explaining how you solved your problem